# St. Peterbourg paradox - expected value of both players

Tags: paradox, economics

Im reading a paper by Karl Menger about the St. Peterbourg paradox (see below): his point is that the paradox does not rely on a mathematical expectation of infinite value, but on the discrepancy between the behaviour (how much player B would pay for the expected results) and the expected result.

The lottery is always presented in terms that A will pay to B each time a flipped coin turn heads.
But the lottery never takes into consideration the expected value for A in committing the game.

It may sound a stupid question, but if the paradox is in the behaviour of B VS the expected value he could get from keeping on playing on the lottery,

- which is the expected value for A?

---

The paradox :

> In the theory of probability, the "Petersburg Game" designates the
> follow- ing gamei between two persons, A and B. Initially, A requires
> that B place a certain bet with A. Then they flip a coin. If it shows
> heads, then B receives 1 dollar from A, and the game is over. If it
> shows tails, it is flipped again. If the second throw turns up heads,
> then B receives 2 dollars from A, and the game ends. The coin is
> flipped until heads appears for the first time. If this happens at the
> nth throw (that is, if the first n - 1 throws aII come up tails, but
> the nth throw is heads), then B receives 2n - 1 dollars from A and the
> game ends. Depending on whether n = 1, 2, 3, 4, ... , B wins 2° = 1,21
> = 2,22 = 4, 23 = 8, ... dollars. What bet should B be willing to make? What is B's mathematical expectation?

Karl Menger, The Role Of Uncertainty In Economics, 1979.

Comment: Everything B wins is received from A.  Therefore, A's expectation is the negative of B's expectation.

Comment: But if so, from a point of view of behavioral economics (Menger points the discussion on the behavior) A will never commit to a game, won't it ? Can you make examples of negative expectations in gambling or investment,  people committing to it in spite of negative expectations ?

Comment: Sure: people who are risk-seekers play games with negative expectations all the time. That's the crux of the definition of "risk seeker." Indeed, anybody who plays an actual government-sponsored lottery is in such a position (with very few exceptions).

Comment: but they are not in negative expectation. They are in 1/n expectation where n is the number of tickets, times the ratio between price of tickets to prize.

Comment: I think we might be using "expectation" in different senses.  Someone who is a risk taker is willing to undertake a bet with negative expectation, where "expectation" is used according to the standard sense in probability theory.